# How to force Knitr to evaluate \Sexpr after all other code chunks

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I am trying to write an abstract for a dynamic document, but my `\Sexpr{}` calls are not working.

Essentially all I am trying to do is start the document off with an abstract that has p-values generated from `\Sexpr{value}` where value is determined "downstream" in the document.  For example

This works:

```
\begin{document}

<<foo>>=
   value = 10
@

Today I bought \Sexpr{value} Salamanders

\end{document}
```

This does not work (and what I am trying to accomplish)

```
\begin{document}

Today I bought \Sexpr{value} Salamanders

<<foo>>=
  value = 10
@
```

Comment: you'll probably have to run two passes through the document, save the stuff you want from later calculations, and load it back in at the beginning.

Comment: It's normal.
In your first example you had defined "value" before you call it in \Sexpr{}; so it exists in your work-space and can be called. And in your second example you call nonexistent variable; so you need to define it first or load a work-space where it exists.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see a straightforward solution to postpone evaluation of `\Sexpr` after evaluation of code chunks, but it is still easy to use `\Sexp` with values defined later in, for example, an abstract: Use a separate file (`myabstract.Rnw`) for the abstract, add `\input{myabstract}` where the abstract is supposed to be included and `knit` `myabstract.Rnw` at the very end of the main document:

**`document.Rnw`:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
  \input{myabstract}
\end{abstract}

Main text.

<<>>=
answer <- 42
@

\end{document}

<<include = FALSE>>=
knit("myabstract.Rnw")
@
```

**`myabstract.Rnw`:**

```
The answer is \Sexpr{answer}.
```

Key to understanding how this works is to realize that `knitr` processes the document before LaTeX does. Therefore, it doesn't matter that the LaTeX command `\input{myabstract}` includes `myabstract.tex` "before" (not referring to time but referring to the line number), `knit("myabstract.Rnw")` generates `myabstract.tex`.

---

For more complex scenarios, evaluation and output could be separated: Do all the calculations in early chunks and print the results where they belong. To show source code, [reuse](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/reference/) chunks (setting `eval = FALSE`). Using the example from above, that means:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<calculation, include = FALSE>>=
answer <- 42
@

\begin{abstract}
  The answer is \Sexpr{answer}.
\end{abstract}

Main text.

<<calculation, eval = FALSE>>=
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd imagined that there might be some way to add some `eval` command that cached the chuck for a `\Sexp` higher up. If I understand it correct Knitr is utilizing Latexmk to run the LaTeX code (several times)?

Comment: No latexmk or several runs are not involved. The chunks in document.Rnw are executed one by one in the given order. The last of these chunks knits myabstract.Rnw to myabstract.tex (try it!). Note that all objects available in the environment where knit() is called are available in the document that is knitted. Therefore,  the object `answer` is available when knitting myabstract.Rnw. After all the knitting is done, the usual TEX toolchain compiles mydocument.tex to PDF. At that point, myabstract.tex exists and can be included where appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

From an intuitive point of view it makes sense that this throws an error: How can you talk about the value of an object that is yet to be computed?

A possible workaround is to run the code chunk before but have `include=FALSE` and then reuse the code chunk later, see [Chunk Reference/Macro: How to reuse chunks | knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/reference/)

```
\begin{document}

%%# Code is evaluated but nothing is written in the output
<<foo, include=FALSE>>=
    value = 10
    plot(sin)
    rnorm(5)
@

Today I bought \Sexpr{value} Salamanders

%%# Here code can be included in the output (figure, echo, results etc.)
<<bar>>=
<<foo>>
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: I wasn't aware you could recycle chunks like this. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Eric Note that there is a more compact syntax for chunk reuse, see the referenced documentation page or the second part of my answer above.