# Can you make inline chunks in knitr evaluate last?

Tags: r, knitr

I am using knitr to write a manuscript. 
I am using inline chunks to make sure the text matches my actual data. 
For example "I performed regression on \rinline{nrow(df)} data points."

However, this information is needed in the abstract and other early parts of the text, while `df` is created by code that is next to the methods section that explains how it is created.

**Can I force all inline chunks to evaluate last?**

To be clear here is a markdown example.

````
Abstract
---------
My study is really interesting.
I performed regression on `r nrow(df)` data points.

Methods 
--------

I used simulated data drawn from a normal distribution.

```{r data}

df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))
```
````

The second sentence in the abstract should read "I performed regression on 10 data points."

Comment: Related (although a special case): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24498362/how-to-force-knitr-to-evaluate-sexpr-after-all-other-code-chunks

Comment: @CL. Thanks for this. Definitely related, not sure I can usefully apply it to my case.

Comment: I don't think that it can be applied to your case. But future readers interested in "evaluating inline code last" might find it helpful, that's why I posted the link.

Answer (score 1):

In writing the MRE I discovered the answer.

If you knit the document in an R session, the variables will be saved to the global namespace. 
Knitting the document a second time will fill in the inline chunks.

I didn't get any errors in the first knit.
So you do need to check that the final document does contain all the inline values.

Comment: that's not how knitr should work, can you show an example how you get this behavior ?

Comment: Using the example in the question, run `knit` once gives "I performed regression on  data points." (two spaces). Running a second time (within same R session) gives "I performed regression on 10 data points."

Comment: I'm now less sure that this works as I thought. I might have run without the inline bit then added the inline chunk and rerun.

Comment: I don't see a problem with this solution. Works fine for me and the concept is reasonable. In the first run `df` does not exist when used in the inline chunk. When the `data` chunk is evaluated, `df` is created in the global environment. Calling `knit` a second time produces the desired document, because now the inline chunk uses `df` from the global environment.